# Using sed command in complex query

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command

So far I've been using sed command in easy cases like change every number 123 to 456 in every line in file, but now I have to do more complex query and I need help. Do you know how can I use sed command to solve this problem:

In every line in file abc.txt if there exists a number from set (123, 456, 789) and there exists number 4242 change number 4242 to 2424?

Comment: add sample input/output to question to make it clearer.. for example, you need to check all three or any of the three numbers mentioned..their order and so on... as to solving with sed, check https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses

Comment: Use other tools? Although `sed` is TC, it should not be used in all cases. (EDIT I may be wrong...)

Comment: I want to change 4242 to 2424 only if in line exists at least one number from set (123, 456, 789)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/123\|456\|789/ s/4242/2424/'
```

The first part is an "address", the following substitution happens only if the address matches. `\|` means "or", it separates alternatives, so any of the numbers matches.

Comment: Though it will match if the line contains 21234242 and change the number to 2132424.

Comment: @tripleee: That fits one of the interpretations of the specification.

Comment: Quite so, but it might be surprising to the OP if that's not what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling extended regular expressions

```
sed -E '/(123|456|789)/s/4242/2424/' file
```

should do that.